# Lumify: Not Launching Local Instance on Vagrant

Tags: yum

Followed the instructions to run a local instance of lumify using Vagrant.
Vagrant up demo, fails as the https://bits.lumify.io/yum/repodata/repomd.xml is down.
The try site is down as https://try.lumify.io/ as well.
Need pointers if any yum repo can be used for this.
I see that there are few dependencies related to opencv etc and i could not find them all in 1 place.
Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure active development of Lumify's open source version ended in 2015. Have you tried the [open source version of Visallo](http://docs.visallo.org)? There's also an [enterprise edition](https://www.visallo.com) if you need additional capabilities or greater scalability.